# Could you please help solve a linear algebra problem?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

$A$ is a 3×3 matrix such that $A^3-6A^2+11A=6I$ 
Find the eigenvalue(s) of A.

** I'm terribly sorry. I have just edited the question. 
 
$A^3-6A^2+11A=6I$

 NOT $A^3-6A^2+11A=6A$

Comment: Hint#1: $x^3-6x^2+5x=x(x-1)(x-5)$. Hint#2: Cayley-Hamilton

Comment: Hint: [Cayley Hamilton theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem).

Comment: @Mathman2017 You've just changed the equation and now neither of the answers match your updated question...

Comment: @Mathman2017 You can still use the approach in Ahmed's answer.  The polynomial will just factor a little differently (but still in an easy way).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $A$ is a $3 \times 3$ matrix, so that the characteristic polynomial is of order $3$.
Now $$A^3 - 6A^2 + 11A - 6I= (A-I)(A-2I)(A-3I) = 0$$
Therefore $(x-1)(x-2)(x-3) = 0$. So that the eigenvalues is some subset of $\{1, 2,3\}$.

Comment: I have edited my answer @Mathman2017.

Comment: What do you mean by "some subset"?

Comment: Because we don't know for sure that that polynomial is minimal or the characteristic polynomial, all we can say is that the set of eigenvalues is some subset of $\{0,1,5\}$ (for instance the identity matrix -- which obviously only has eigenvalue 1 -- satisfies this polynomial).
@Bye_World beautiful answer.

Comment: What do you mean by "minimal"?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_polynomial_(linear_algebra)

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Assuming $A$ is diagonalizable, we can write $A = PDP^{-1}$. It is not hard to see then that $A^n = PD^nP{-1}$, where the elements of $D^n$ are just the elements of the diagonal matrix $D$ raised to the $n$. Then solving your equation, we'd have

$PD^3P^{-1} - 6PD^2P^{-1} +5PDP^{-1}=0$

so

$P(D^3 -6D^2 +5D)P^{-1}$ is the zero matrix. So you want to solve $D^3 -6D^2 +5D = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

You know Cayley Hamilton theorem here - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem,

a nice and powerful theorem.

So applying Cayley Hamilton theorem we get if $\lambda$ is an eigen value then it satisfies $\lambda^3 - 6\lambda^2 + 11 \lambda = 6$,little eyeballing give us $\lambda = 1$ as a root of the above cubic equation and if you work out for the next two roots they will be $2,3$,so there are three Eigen values as $1,2,3$.